# Behavior of $|\Gamma(z)|$ as $\text{Im} (z) \to \pm \infty$

Tags: complex-analysis, asymptotics, gamma-function

Let $\Gamma(z)$ be the gamma function.

In a paper I'm reading, the author states that $$ |\Gamma(z)| = |\Gamma(a+ib)|  \sim \sqrt{2 \pi} |b|^{a-\frac{1}{2}} e^{-|b|\frac{\pi}{2}}$$ as $|b| \to \infty$.

Can this asymptotic behavior be derived from Stirling's formula?

**EDIT**:

I think I have something.

Assume that $a,b >0$ and that $b$ is very large.

Then it would seem that
$$ \begin{align}|\Gamma(a+ib)|  &\sim \left|\sqrt{\frac{2 \pi}{a+ib}} \Big(\frac{a+ib}{e}\Big)^{a+ib} \right| \\ &= \sqrt{2 \pi}  \left|(a+ib)^{a-\frac{1}{2}} \right| \left| (a+ib)^{ib} \right| \left|e^{-a-ib} \right| \\ &= \sqrt{2 \pi} \left(\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}} \right)^{a- \frac{1}{2}} \ \left|\left(\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}} e^{i \arg \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)} \right)^{ib} \right| e^{-a} \\ &= \sqrt{2 \pi} \left(\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}} \right)^{a- \frac{1}{2}} e^{-b \arg \left(\frac{b}{a} \right)} e^{-a} \\   &\sim \sqrt{2 \pi} \, b^{a - \frac{1}{2}} e^{-b \frac{\pi}{2}} {\color{red}{e^{-a}}}. \end{align}$$

But apparently this is not quite correct.

Comment: Something is fishy.  My calculation agrees with yours but it is wrong numerically.  According to Mathematica, $$|\Gamma(1/2+3i)| \approx 0.02251777120$$ and $$\left.\sqrt{2 \pi} |b|^{a - \frac{1}{2}} e^{-|b| \frac{\pi}{2}} e^{-a}\right|_{\{a=1/2,b=3\}} \approx 0.01365771867,$$ but $$\left.\sqrt{2 \pi} |b|^{a - \frac{1}{2}} e^{-|b| \frac{\pi}{2}} \right|_{\{a=1/2,b=3\}} \approx 0.02251777127.$$  And the approximation gets better as $b$ increases.

Comment: I don't think anything is fishy since we're dealing with an expansion for when $|z|$ is large. But why would dropping the $e^{-a}$ term give a good approximation for a case when $|z|$ is not large?

Comment: The approximation without the $e^{-a}$ factor is still virtually perfect for larger $b$ and the version with the $e^{-a}$ factor is still off.  For a more extreme example, the approximation without the $e^{-a}$ factor at $z = 1/2+20i$ is accurate to $67$ decimal places ($13$ of which are leading zeros).

Comment: @AntonioVargas I've addressed the discrepancy, and rectified my earlier answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $z=a+ib$.  As $\vert  b \vert \to \infty$, the argument of $z$ does not approach $\pi$.  Thus Stirling's approximation applies, giving

$$\vert \Gamma(z) \vert \sim \left\vert \sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{a+ib}}\left(\frac{a+ib}{e}\right)^{a+ib}\right\vert\sim \sqrt{2\pi}\left\vert(ib)^{-1/2}\left(\frac{a+ib}{e}\right)^{a+ib}\right\vert$$
$$\sim\sqrt{2\pi}\vert b \vert^{-1/2} \left\vert \left(\frac{a+ib}{e}\right)^{a+ib}\right\vert \sim \sqrt{2\pi}\vert b \vert^{-1/2}e^{-a} \vert z^z\vert,$$

The $\vert z^z \vert$ term above satisfies

$$\vert z^z \vert = \vert e^{z \log z} \vert = \vert e^{(a+ib)(\log \vert z \vert + i \mathrm{arg}z)}\vert=e^{a \log \vert z \vert-b \mathrm{arg} z} \sim \vert b \vert^a e^{-b \mathrm{arg} z}$$
because $\vert z \vert \sim \vert b \vert$ as $b \to \infty$.  Thus, it remains to approximate $e^{-b \,\mathrm{arg z}}$ as $\vert b \vert \to \infty$.

*Note: An easy mistake at this point is the false implication*
$$\mathrm{arg}z \to \pm \pi/2 \quad \Longrightarrow \quad e^{b \mathrm{arg} z} \to e^{\pm b \pi/2}.$$
*However, this need not hold, because the exponential is sensitive to non-dominant terms.*

We compute
$$\lim_{\vert b \vert \to \infty} e^{-b\, \mathrm{arg} z}e^{-a+\vert b \vert \pi/2}=\mathrm{exp}\lim_{\vert b \vert \to \infty}\left(-b \arctan(b/a)-a+\vert b \vert \pi/2\right)$$
$$=\mathrm{exp}\lim_{\vert b \vert \to \infty}-b\left(\frac{\pm\pi}{2}-\frac{a}{b}+O\left(\vert b \vert^{-3}\right)\right)-a+\vert b \vert \pi/2,$$
in which we take the positive sign if $b \to \infty$ and the negative sign if $b \to -\infty$.  *(This is simply the Taylor series to $\arctan(b/a)$ at $\pm \infty$.)* Therefore we can replace said $\pm$ with $\vert b \vert/b$, at which point we see that our limit is $1$.

Thus
$$\vert \Gamma(z) \vert \sim \sqrt{2\pi}\vert b \vert^{-1/2}e^{-a}\vert b \vert^a e^{-b \,\mathrm{arg} z} \sim \sqrt{2\pi}\vert b \vert^{-1/2}e^{-a}\vert b \vert^a e^{a-\vert b \vert \pi/2}$$
$$\sim\sqrt{2\pi}\vert b \vert^{a-1/2} e^{-\vert b \vert \pi/2},$$
as claimed.

Comment: I got the same answer but Mathematica seems to say there is no factor of $e^{-a}$ (at least numerically).  [See my comment above](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/398260/behavior-of-gammaz-as-textim-z-to-pm-infty#comment852960_398260).

Comment: I got that extra term, too, as you can see in the edit to my original post.  Would there be any reason to drop it?

Comment: @RandomVariable I've fixed my answer, and alluded to the common error we encountered along the way.

Comment: Ah, there it is.  It makes sense (after the fact) that the factor of $b$ in front forces us to consider at least one more term in the expansion.  Thanks for seeing it, A Walker!  (+1)

Answer (score 2):

Assume $|y|\gg|x|$. Note that
$$
\begin{align}
y\arctan\!2(y,x)
&=|y|\arctan\!2(|y|,x)\\[6pt]
&=\frac\pi2|y|-|y|\arctan\!2(x,|y|)\\
&\sim\frac\pi2|y|-x
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
x^2+y^2\sim|y|^2
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\left|\sqrt{2\pi}\,\frac{\color{#C00}{z^{z-1/2}}}{\color{#090}{e^z}}\right|
&=\sqrt{2\pi}\color{#C00}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^{x/2-1/4}}e^{\color{#090}{-x}\color{#C00}{-y\arctan\!2(y,x)}}\\
&\sim\sqrt{2\pi}\,|y|^{x-1/2}e^{-\frac\pi2|y|}
\end{align}
$$